Concatenating values in rows and columns together in a single cell
I have a table which has three columns - company name, investor and stake held in the company by investor. In the output, I want all investors of a particular company in a single row separated by commas alongwith their corresponding stake, and that too in a single cell. Stake can be null for a given investor.
Current table:



Company
Investor
Stake




A
C
40%


A
D
30%


B
E



B
F
10%



Output required:



Company
Investor & Stake




A
C - 40%; D - 30%


B
E; F - 10%



I have already used stuff function to combine the investors and stakes in two separate columns, in a single row, but unable to combine stake with investors in a single cell.

Please provide the required [mre] which shows: what you have tried, as well as the specific issue with your attempt.  In addition, Please properly tag your question with the language in which you are working.
